# Stealing shared title

Tags: nevada

Here's the situation

I bought a car with someone as an OR title. I was supposed to be mailed a title as was she.

She took both titles signed the car to herself and took the car. My mail was stolen.

Is all of this legal? Are there any damages?

Comment: Theft of mail is a crime in itself. Apart from that the whole thing *sounds* illegal, but without more information its hard to tell. If she forged your signature or wrote something false in order to use your title document then that is also a crime. Perhaps you need to talk to the police.

Comment: What is an "OR" title?

Comment: She didn't forge anything she just stole the mail.

Comment: An or title means either party can sell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theft of mail is a [federal felony](https://www.shouselaw.com/nevada/NV-mail-theft.html):

> Under 18 USC 1708, it is a crime to destroy, steal or even possess mail belonging to another. If you fail to return mail you received in error, you could be charged with the federal felony crime of mail theft. Mail theft can be punished by:
>
> - Up to 5 years in a federal penitentiary, and/or
> - A fine of up to $250,000.

From what you say it sounds like the actual sale was not fraudulent, but as a part owner you would be entitled to your share of the proceeds; the other owner can't simply make off with them. If she does then that might count as theft, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: I'm pretty sure just not paying their share of the proceeds wouldn't count as theft. Owing and not paying money is not considered theft almost anywhere. Fraud, it could be (in some laws any "dishonest act" counts). Most likely though, just cause for civil but not criminal action.